# Left and right invariant vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm following Woodhouse's book on geometric quantization and I'm stuck with this problem.

Let $R_A$ and $L_A$ be right and left invariant vector fields such that $R_A(e)=A=L_A(e)$, where $A$ is an element of Lie algebra.

How can I show that $[R_A,R_B]=-R_{[A,B]}$, $[L_A,L_B]=L_{[A,B]}$ and $[R_A, L_B]=0$ ?

The hint is to use BCH formula in a form: $\exp(sA) \exp(sB) \approx \exp(st[A,B]) \exp(tB) \exp(sA)$. I can differentiate this expression with respect to s and t but I don't know how to get vector field commutators from this.

Comment: Do you know that you can write the bracket of two vector fields as a second derivative of the commutator of their flows?

Comment: I don't know that. How does this help me?

Comment: I haven't thought this true but you said you do not know how to get teh bracket so maybe this helps: $[X,Y](x)=\frac 1 2\frac{d^2}{d^2t} \Phi^Y_{-t}\circ  \Phi^X_{-t} \circ  \Phi^Y_{t}\circ  \Phi^X_{t}(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can do this using the BCH formula as follows: It's an easy exercise, to check that the flow of left and right invariant vector fields generated by $A$ is right and left multiplication with $\exp (tA)$ respectivly: $F^{R_A}_t = L_{\exp(tA)}$ and $F^{L_A}_t = R_{\exp(tA)}$. 
Plugging this and the BCH formula in the formula for the commutator of vectorfields is in terms of the lie derivative will probably give the result. This is, what you start with to plug the BCH formula in:
\begin{align*}
[R_A,R_B]_g 
&= \mathcal{L}_{R_A} R_B (g) 
=\frac{d}{dt} \Big\vert_{t=0} (F^{R_A}_{-t})_* (R_B)_{F^{R_A}_t (g)} \\
&= \frac{d}{dt} \Big\vert_{t=0} \frac{d}{ds} \Big\vert_{s=0} (F^{R_A}_{-t}) \circ (F^{R_B}_{t}) \circ (F^{R_A}_{t}) (g) \\
&= \frac{d}{dt} \Big\vert_{t=0} \frac{d}{ds} \Big\vert_{s=0} \exp(-tA) \cdot \exp (sB) \cdot \exp (tA) \cdot g
\end{align*}

However, a much easier way is to note, that right invariant vector fields are $R_g$-related to themselves for every element $g$ of the Liegroup. And as for every smooth map between manifolds $f$ the commutator of $f$-related vector fields is again $f$-related, the commuator $[R_A, R_B]$ is again $R_g$-related to itself for every $g$ in the Liegroup and is thus right invariant. Now all you need to do is to check, that $[R_A, R_B]_e = -[L_A, L_B]_e = -[A,B]$. This is easily done by continuing the calculation I started above with $g = e$, as $$\exp(-tA) \cdot \exp (sB) \cdot \exp (tA) = R_{\exp(tA)} \circ R_{\exp(sB)} \circ R_{\exp(-tA)} (e) = (F^{L_{-A}}_{-t}) \circ (F^{L_B}_{t}) \circ (F^{L_{-A}}_{t}) (e).$$

The fomula for left invariant vectorfields is derived in the exact same way. Finally the commuator of a left and a right invariant vector field vanishes  as 
$$ [R_A,L_B]_g 
= \mathcal{L}_{R_A} R_B (g) 
=\frac{d}{dt} \Big\vert_{t=0} (F^{R_A}_{-t})_* (L_B)_{F^{R_A}_t (g)}
=\frac{d}{dt} \Big\vert_{t=0} (L_{\exp (-tA)})_* (L_{\exp (tA)})_* (L_g)_* B
= 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about f-relatedness, I will have to read up on it but the other stuff seems clear.

Comment: $f$-relatedness is not a big secret... Suppose $f: M \to N$ is a smooth map between smooth manifolds. Let $X,Y$ be vector fields on $M$ an $\widehat{X}, \widehat{Y}$ vector fields on $N$. Then $X$ and $\widehat{X}$ are $f$-related, iff $df_p X_p = \widehat{X}_{f(p)}$ for every $p \in M$. Same thing for $Y$ and $\widehat{Y}$. It's quite easy to check that we then have $df_p [X,Y]_p = [\widehat{X}, \widehat{Y}]_{f(p)}$ by plugging in a smooth funtion $\psi: N \to \Bbb R$ on both sides.

Comment: So to be clear, one form $df_p$ acts on $X_p$, how does it produce vector field?

Comment: By $df_p$ I mean the differential of the map $f: M \to N$ at $p \in M$. It takes a tangent vector at $p$ and produces one in $f(p)$. But in general, it doesn't produce a vector field as if $f$ is not injective it might produce competing values for the the same point in $N$, while if $f$ is not surjective, it doesn't define a value everywhere. How the differential produces a tangent vector depends on what a tangent vector is for you...

Comment: I don't really see it, don't you need like a push forward operation to define the vector field with a hat on $N$ in point $f(p)$? $df_pX_p$ is a number and $\hat{X}_{f(p)}$ is a vector. How does this equation hold?

Comment: No, $df_p X_p$ is _not_ a number, it _is_ a vector. And yes it is sometimes calles push forward. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29](wikipedia). But the differential in $p$ pushes forward only single vectors, not vector _fields_, as this can produce conflicts if $f$ is not a diffeomorphism, see my earlier comment. This is why you need a predefined vector field $\widehat{X}$ on $N$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40813/discussion-between-hase-olaf-and-caims).